# C++ Issues using Named Shared Memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I've tried to implement a shared memory interface, however I am not able to get it working.

Since it isn't yet working I want to ask help.
A shared memory is necessary for my application which is an Multiobjective Evolutionary Algorithm that runs on several processes, however the various processes need to exchange information, and instead of dumping it into  a physical file a billion times, I'd rather share memory using this method.

I am on Win7x64 using C++ in VS v120.
For the sake of testing, all of this code takes place in the same process until I've figured it out.

My filename is a const string

```
 m_Filename = "Local\\shared_memory"

 m_BufferSize = 1024
```

**EDIT 1:**

So I see there is some confusion as to what I am trying to do here, well I am confused as well.
Looking at the official documentation from MSDN it uses the file mapping with *INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE*, and they don't seem to create a file on disk. 
This is fine for my solution. I don't need a file on disk, although either works.
The reason I tried to do it the other way is because the first method failed and I started searching, and I came across threads on here where people say that they need to make the actual file as well.

This is a more complete code, and yes I do check the error codes.

The m_Filename is set in the class constructor. Buffer size is constant.
I've removed my code which does the physical file stuff, I guess it isn't actually required?

```
    void MemoryMapper::_CreateMappedFile() {

    m_Handle = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,
        0, m_BufferSize, m_Filename.c_str());

    if (m_Handle == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << m_DebugErrorTitle << "_CreateMappedFile(): " << MM_ERROR_CREATE_FAILED << 
            " (" << GetLastError() << ")" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    m_pBuffer = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(m_Handle, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, m_BufferSize);

    if (m_pBuffer == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << m_DebugErrorTitle << "_CreateMappedFile(): " << MM_ERROR_MAPPING_FAILED << 
            " (" << GetLastError() << ")" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(m_Handle);
        return;
    }

    TCHAR szMsg[] = TEXT("Test message.");
    CopyMemory((PVOID)m_pBuffer, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));

    if (!UnmapViewOfFile(m_pBuffer)) {
        std::cout << m_DebugErrorTitle << "_CreateMappedFile(): UnmapViewOfFile() returned false. (" << GetLastError() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    if (!CloseHandle(m_Handle)) {
        std::cout << m_DebugErrorTitle << "_CreateMappedFile(): CloseHandle() returned false. (" << GetLastError() << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    if (m_Debug > 1) { std::cout << m_DebugTitle << "Created mapped file: '" << m_Filename << "'." << std::endl; }
}
```

Running this code and I end up with the console message:
[MemoryMapper] Created mapped file: 'Local\shared_memory'.

Then, in the same process, for the sake of testing?? I try to open the file again.
This time I get error code 2 saying the file doesn't exist.

```
bool MemoryMapper::_Open(const std::string& fn) {

    if (m_Debug > 2) { std::cout << m_DebugTitle << "Open '" << fn << "'." << std::endl; }

    m_OpenHandle = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, fn.c_str());

    if (m_OpenHandle == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << m_DebugErrorTitle << " _Open('" << fn << "'): " << MM_ERROR_OPEN_FAILED << " (" << GetLastError() << ")" << std::endl;
        m_IsOpen = false;
        return m_IsOpen;
    }
    m_IsOpen = true;
    if (m_Debug > 1) { std::cout << m_DebugTitle << "Open: " << std::to_string(m_IsOpen) << std::endl; }
    return m_IsOpen;
}
```

The filename is the same. 100%.

Why can't I open the file?

Also, should I be checking if a shared memory object exists with the set filename before creating one? Does the object get cleared away when the application terminates?

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that the handle given from the initial CreateFileMapping() must remain open for the duration I want to use the shared object?

I attempted this and now it seems to work fine.
I can make the object, open it, write and close it using separate calls.
My mistake was closing the handle upon creation, although, which is correct?

Comment: for what you create file at all ?

Comment: Try passing `file_handle` as the first parameter to `CreateFileMapping`.

Comment: Always check error codes, but ONLY when functions fail. Check if `CreateFileMapping()` is returning NULL or not before you call `OpenFileMapping()`.  If it does, then call `GetLastError()` to find out why, otherwise don't call `GetLastError()` at all, as you might get an error code from an earlier operation

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - and what this changed ? (in sense error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` )

Comment: @RbMm: If you pass `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` as the first parameter of `CreateFileMapping()`, then the mapping will be linked to a block of memory backed by the system paging file, not the file that was opened with `CreateFile()`. IOW, the contents of the file won't be shared with anyone who opens a handle to the `Local\shared_memory` mapping.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i of course know this. but how this change error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. unclear for what here created file at all

Comment: @RemyLebeau - and problem here faster not in some api call failed, but in not understanding what is being done. for what file on disk (with name `"Local\\shared_memory"` !) when need implement a shared memory interface ? faster of all first process just close handle to section before second process open it. but without actual code, this is only guess

Comment: @RbMm: `"Local\shared_memory"` is name of the mapping object, not the file on disk. The memory object can still be shared while being backed by a physical file, whether that be an actual file or the system paging file, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, did not notice that file used another name, but how all this change main question - 1.)for what create file on disk at all ? 2) how this affect `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` ?

Comment: @RbMm: `CreateFileMapping()` can't report `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, except *MAYBE* if `CreateFileMapping()` succeeds and creates a new mapping that did not previous exist, but the result of `GetLastError()` is undefined in that situation. The only error code that is valid on success is `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. That goes back to my earlier comment: "*Always check error codes, but ONLY when functions fail*". Without a [mcve], we can't see how the OP is checking errors.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - `OpenFileMapping` **can** and report `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` if object with this name not exist. here you mistake

Comment: @RbMm: They **MAY OR MAY NOT** return that error code, that behavior is **UNDEFINED** on MSDN.  The ONLY documented error code for `CreateFileMapping()` is `ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST`.  No error codes are documented for `OpenFileMapping()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` - this is come from `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` - well known error when we try open any object in nt namespace if this name not exist

Comment: in any case almost 100% that section handle created by call `CreateFileMapping` was closed before call `OpenFileMapping`. in this case (path correct, but name not exist) will be exactly error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: CreateFile is opening `fn.c_str()` whereas CreateFileMapping is being passed `m_Filename.c_str()`..

Comment: @Brandon My bad. It's actually the same filename, though. just forgot to edit in the actual variable name. Posting an updated description now

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for the reply. I've updated my code. I tried what you suggested before, but I am not able to get it working.

Comment: @RbMm I've updated the thread to show a more complete code example. I hope this answers some questions regarding the interface. I've tried various suggestions in here and other threads, I can't get past the current stage.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the insight. I've updated my code to try and give a better explanation.

Comment: @MadsMidtlyng - so i was correct at begin - `CloseHandle(m_Handle)` - you close your section object.

Comment: after you return from `MemoryMapper::_CreateMappedFile()` your section no more exist.

Comment: @RbMm Good call! Is is correct to assume that the initial handle from creating the object must remain open until I want to discard the whole shared object? Thus the master process closes it at its own termination, letting child processes access it during.

Comment: @MadsMidtlyng - but are you read my answer ? just about this i and wrote. after you close last handle to object - it disappears from NT-namespace (no more name). and because no even more reference to it - it destroyed. your code in `MemoryMapper::_CreateMappedFile() ` is doing nothing - create temorary object and than destroy it

Comment: @RbMm I read it, and other threads, which is why I was a little confused, a lot of people giving contradictory advice across the threads, but I'm happy that you told me the correct way. I was able to understand the concept of shared memory better because of this.

Comment: @MadsMidtlyng - different windows objects, unlike files on disk, if temporary. it live in memory only and was deleted when last reference to it is deleted. so if you create object, and then close it handle - in general object will be deleted. this is general point, not only for section - for all named objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, if you tried to implement a shared memory interface - for what you create file on disk ? you can do this, but it absolute not need in this case

> (3) Now the object in itself should exist in memory, no?

now object really exist in NT-namespace but until you not close last handle to it. when last handle is closed, object name is removed from NT-namespace, unless you not use `OBJ_PERMANENT` flag in [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749(v=vs.85).aspx). but for this need use `NtCreateSection` instead `CreateFileMapping` and have `SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_PRIVILEGE`

if `OpenFileMapping` fail with error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` this mean that name, which you using in call, not exist in NT Namespace. this can be by several reasons: - the process, which call `OpenFileMapping` run under another terminal session ( `Local\shared_memory` is expanded to `\Sessions\<SessionId>\BaseNamedObjects\shared_memory` or to `\BaseNamedObjects\shared_memory` if you run it from session 0). you can simply mistake with name.

but faster of all - you close section handle, returned by `CreateFileMapping` before you call `OpenFileMapping`. because you not use `OBJ_PERMANENT` object name deleted when all open handles to them are closed. object itself can continue exist if exist references to it - say when you call `MapViewOfFile` - you create reference to section - and it will be not deleted until you not unmap it, but section name will be removed anyway, when all open handles to them are closed.

---

how i and assume at begin - `OpenFileMapping` fail because section no more exist at time which it called. it handles already closed. `void MemoryMapper::_CreateMappedFile()` by fact do nothing - this function create **temporary** object, do some manipulations with it and destroy at exit. all this have no any affect after function return

Comment: If you really need to create a permanent object via the native API -- which I doubt -- then it should be created globally in "\BaseNamedObjects". If you simply need cross-session object support, the Windows API supports this via the "Global" link to "\BaseNamedObjects", e.g. "Global\shared_memory". There are also undocumented "Session" and "AppContainerNamedObjects" links, e.g. "Session\2\shared_memory". These relative paths must use backslash as the path separator. Slash is just a name character in the object namespace; it's only a reserved character in filesystems.